# Use GoogleMaps SDK to generate routes?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am very new and struggling with the Google Maps sdk. Is it possible to use the google maps sdk to actually generate a route? Like if I could make a button that said "Generate Route" and then once clicked it generates a route that the user could actually navigate like they were using the real google maps app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
func getDiectionFromGoogle(startCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(startCoordinate.latitude),\(startCoordinate.longitude)&destination=\(toLocation.latitude),\(toLocation.longitude)&key=\("your key!!")"
    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let placesTask = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
        }
        if let jsonResult = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary {

            // *******UPDATE**********
            print(jsonResult) // this returns a dictionary

            if let routes = jsonResult["routes"] as? NSArray {
                // example to get data from dictionary
            }

        })
        placesTask.resume()
    }
```

See what you get in jsonResult. You can find all the coordinates you need to generate paths for your direction and more!

Also, you can use more parameters in your json request. Take a look here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

**// update on Oct 15**

I guess you are encountering the problem with encoded path. Here is how I decode the path. I am pretty sure I am not doing the simplest way, but I just ignore it because it just works. haha

```
// you can see a key called polyline in somewhere in the dictionary
// polylineCoordinates are all the coordinates for your routes
// path can be used for polyline
if let polyline = (paths[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "polyline") as? NSDictionary {
    if let points = polyline.value(forKey: "points") as? String {
        let gmsPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points)
        for index in 0 ..< gmsPath!.count() {
            let coordinate = gmsPath!.coordinate(at: index)
            self.polylineCoordinates.append(coordinate)
            self.path.add(coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a Google document of how to use polylines. I will not give you any code for this one. I am pretty sure you can solve it. Learning by doing right? But if you stuck with something, you can come back to me. I will try to help:)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes

I am not sure Google provide a navigation like the Google maps or not. I build my app's navigation by myself. I can try to help you with that if I can.

**// update on Oct 20**

You are almost there. The path[i] comes from here LOL. Really ugly code.

```
if let jsonResult = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary {
    if let routes = jsonResult["routes"] as? NSArray {
        if let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs") as? NSArray {
            if let steps = legs.value(forKey: "steps") as? NSArray {
                if steps.count != 0 {
                    if let firstStep = steps.object(at: 0) as? NSArray {
                        if firstStep.count != 0 {
                            if let paths = firstStep.object(at: 0) as? NSArray {
                                if paths.count > 0 {
                                    for i in 0 ..< paths.count {
```

[image]

To see my graph, path[0] is start coordinate to intersection1, path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nENqb.png) is intersection1 to intersection2 and path[2] is intersection2 to end coordinate.

Actually my self.path is useless, you can just decode the path from jsonResult. The reason why I use self.polylineCoordinates is because I want to get all the coordinates (like the red triangle in my graph) to create my own navigation. In jsonResult, you can see some keys called startAt (if I didn't remember it wrong) and endAt, they are coordinates which represents as the black triangle in my graph. The reason why you might need to get all the coordinates is because a path from intersection to another intersection may not be a straight line, it can be a curve like intersection1 to intersection2.

Comment: holy crap this seems awesome! Thanks for taking the time to do this and sorry for the long wait before I reply. However I am quite new to this so I am not quite sure how I could go about displaying this or how/what a json is. could you further explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I want to be clear that I would be doing this from an iOS app, not android!

Comment: This is Swift, so is ios. Mostly or in simple as a beginner, jsonResult returns a dictionary like {"name": {"John": "male", "Mary": "female", "Bob": "male}}

Comment: so were I to put the above code into my viewController.swift, would I be able to link that function to a button and whenever the user clicks the button, they would be prompted for a location to go to, and then the function would run and display results?

Comment: Yes. you can. Try to take a look (print) on what you get in jsonResult first. Then convert the data.

Comment: Thank you very much you have been quite helpful!

Comment: I am having trouble actually printing the json Result.

Comment: Currently I have this:  if ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary) != nil {
                print("Start: \(startCoordinate.latitude), \(startCoordinate.longitude) End: \(toLocation.latitude), \(toLocation.longitude)")
            }                                                                                                                 all this does is print the location i am at and the place that the user inputs. how can I actually print what I receive from google? Thanks!

Comment: You should print(jsonResult). I just updated how to print jsonResult and its associated value. Let me know if you still stuck with getting the route

Comment: You can update your code in your post, so people can see your code clearly.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! It is definitely working, however Im getting an error saying that my IP, site, or mobile application isnt authorized to use my API key. It says it received a request from my IP address with an empty referer? This is odd to me because i have used the google api console to get an api key, and i even set its restrictions to iOS and put in the appropriate bundle identifier. Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: I took off the restriction of the API key and now it works! This is pretty cool stuff. Now I can learn how dictionaries work and use the data from the Json to place polylines on my map (I think). Will it ever be possible to have the user actually click on a "navigate" button and have functionality similar to the google maps app?

Comment: Also, I am looking at my json results and see data like this:                  "points" : "_cmzExhj_NjBF~@E|@QRz@DjAaANsA\\sGpBqBr@}CfBcD`BwAd@aAT{AVqDv@wAZy@PwAh@qCt@oAT{BR{@H}ATeBX}Bf@iGdC}AvAaAdAmC|CkAfBm@|Ag@~Ai@`Ca@vCUrAK^u@bBuAdC[`@e@^cBz@l@d@jF~DbE|ClBbB`BhBbHvItIjKrAxAx@fA|@rAf@|@N^JRv@m@jAy@~BiAbBa@rBWzE]rEc@fFa@`BC`BFbEb@h@Bt@Gd@Sb@]^u@P}@DeA@oAE{@Qw@Ym@c@o@kAS}BGuA@DqE?_A                                                           what is this exactly and how can I get it in an unencrypted mode (assuming that is encrypted?)

Comment: Where exactly is "i" coming from in the line "paths[i] as AnyObject"? I am assuming that i is supposed to go from 0 to (lengthOfDictionary - 1)? And if i am understanding this correctly then wherever the key "polyline" is in the jsonResult, it goes within that section and then searches for the key "points" and goes within that section to get the values, and then decrypts them and adds them to a list of some sort. what exactly are self.polylineCoordinates.append(coordinate) and self.path.add(coordinate) doing? Thanks!

Comment: Very detailed, thank you. I am having errors on the self.polylineCoordinates.append(coordinate) and self.path.add(coordinate) lines. I should point out that I am writing all of this in the default ViewController.swift file that is created with the project. The errors I am getting are that "polylineCoordinates" and "path" are not members of ViewController. How I am getting mine to work is using a regular ViewController combined with an MKMapView in the storyboard. Would it make this easier if I stopped using a .nib file altogether and instead created the map like google suggests at this link?

Comment: Yes. It will be definitely easier if you use Google mapView like polyline only can be used in Google mapView.  Did you create these two variable "polylineCoordinates" and "path" outside of the function? like var polylineCoordinte = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

Comment: I am working on converting to Google mapView, but sadly my laptop is experiencing issues and I will have to take a small break from working on this in order to get it fixed. Thanks for the assistance! I will Respond once I get it back up and running. You are great!

Comment: You are welcome:) This is a good excuse to buy the new macbook pro haha

Comment: okay ive finally got my mac back and converted my map to a GMSMap! And it correctly draws a polyline! WOOOO! How can we go about getting the user to navigate this?

Comment: which way do you want to navigate?? Like google? or any new idea??

Comment: I was thinking more of a standard way. Such as googles navigation method. Simply showing the user which turn to make next, displaying arrival time, making the center of the screen be the users location at all times, etc!

Comment: First, you need to find a way keep tracking the user's location like how to enable the user's device GPS and get the CLLocationCoordinate. Second, for the arrival time, you can also find it in your jsonResult like just combining all the travel time. Third, making the center of the screen is easy because you already know how to set the camera.

Comment: That does sound a little easy. If I have any trouble with it I hope you don't mind me posting on here again. Thanks!

Comment: sureeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: I would like to display to the user their next turn, so as an example "Turn right on to main street". However in the JSON Result it has something like this: "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eJoyce Lawrence Ln\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eLocust St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eHoward St\u003c/b\u003e". Is there a way to get this in the correct way?

Comment: I am not sure what it is. Can you send me the whole thing of what you get in jsonResult? I use heading from p1 to p2 and heading from p2 to p3 to get their next turn

Comment: Not really sure how to give you the json because of character limitations... but here is what I am getting in json: "  "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esouth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eAzor Ct\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eEli Hartley Dr\u003c/b\u003e",

Comment: Also, my app generates routes with the appropriate polyline, but it also generates a polyline that is a straight line from the start point to the end point. It is very ugly and invasive. Ever run in to that?

Comment: I will take a look later. quite busy in this week and coming week